# Where do I see what parts of LLVM a library contain?

Tags: c++, llvm

I know how to see which libraries a certain component correponds to with the command:

```
llvm-config --libs core
```

Now, suppose I get a linker error and wants to include another library to resolve it.

Say, the linker can't resolve some symbol `A`. Then how do I:

1) Find the library that contains the specific symbol, like e.g. LLVMCore.lib.

2) Look up contents of libraries to see what symbols it defines?

I don't understand how to do this reading the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already discovered a proper LLVM-way to do this would be using [llvm-config](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-config.html) by indicating the *components* you intend to link against or use, e.g.

```
llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core
```

Other common non-llvm specific methods that you can use to find a symbol: on a Win platform (use VS native tools cmd or equivalent environment-set one):

```
for %f in (*.lib) do (dumpbin.exe /symbols %f | findstr /C:"your_symbol")
```

if you can't deal with findstr's limitations GNU grep might be a better choice.
If you have unix tools installed and in your `PATH` you can also use

```
for %f in (*.lib) do (nm -gC %f | findstr /C:"your_symbol")
```

as [baddger964](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41932580/1938163) suggests.

On a unix system:

```
for lib in $(find . -name \*.so) ; do nm -gC $lib | grep my_symbol | grep -v " U " ; done
```

(search `*.so` libraries in this directory for `my_symbol`; extern-only, demangle and exclude undefined symbols)

Given the above question 2 is trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you also provide the `grep` command used to find a symbol on Linux? Is this the way LLVM programmers normally resolve their symbols, i.e., finds the library that contains it?

Comment: @Shuzheng Edited and added more info

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. It is complete and satisfying :-)
Last question, do you know any ressource where the "components" are defined? Right now, I use `llvm-config` to see what libraries a component relates to. However, it would be nice if there was some ressource saying: "These parts of the LLVM source code is put into this library" and "This component covers libraries  that corresponds to these parts of the source". This way, if I see a symbol is defined in `someheader.hpp`, I can immediately locate the corresponding library.

Answer (score 1):

One way to see symbols of your lib is to use the nm command :

```
nm -gC mylib.so
```